# Fix single entry from mbr

Tags: boot, multi-boot, mbr

I use EasyBCD to manage my tripleboot of (1) Windows Server 2008 R2, (2) Windows 7 Professional and (3) Ubuntu Linux.
While trying to change the order of my boot menu I ended up losing the Windows Server entry. Luckily I had a boot menu backup (.bcd file) that allowed me to restore my boot menu using EasyBCD.

However, when I now select the Windows Server option in my boot menu the Windows Server Recovery Environment starts up. So I have to select language/keyboard layout/etc. and then I have 3 options as shown in the image below.

[image: System Recovery Options]
.

My goal is to **fix the one corrupted Windows Server entry** from my boot menu without messing up or losing the two other ones.

I'm guessing the Recovery Console (Command Prompt) is the next step and that I will be needing bootrec.exe.
But when consulting this page: [Use the Bootrec.exe tool in the Windows Recovery Environment to troubleshoot and repair startup issues in Windows](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927392/en-us) (about half way down there's a link that shows the bootrec.exe options) I'm getting uncertain.

The page lists 4 options for bootrec.exe :

- /FixMbr
- /FixBoot
- /ScanOs
- /RebuildBcd

*What option do I need to fix just the server entry of my boot menu?*

Thanks in advance,

Sander

P.S.
All three OS's are on the same physical disk (3 different partitions).
Disk layout:

1. System reserved (primary partition, 100 MB)
2. Windows 7 (primary parition, 150 GB)
3. Windows Server 2008 (primary partition, 150 GB)
4. Extended partition (linux partitions (/,/swap,/home), 150GB + data partition, 150 GB)

P.P.S.
This is what my boot menu looks like using EasyBCD (Detailed/Debug mode) on my Windows 7 installation.

```
Windows Boot Manager
--------------------
identifier              {9dea862c-5cdd-4e70-acc1-f32b344d4795}
device                  partition=\Device\HarddiskVolume1
description             Windows Boot Manager
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {7ea2e1ac-2e61-4728-aaa3-896d9d0a9f0e}
default                 {93f90e43-cae8-11df-b05a-c9177e705936}
resumeobject            {93f90e3e-cae8-11df-b05a-c9177e705936}
displayorder            {93f90e43-cae8-11df-b05a-c9177e705936}
                        {93f90e3f-cae8-11df-b05a-c9177e705936}
                        {93f90e46-cae8-11df-b05a-c9177e705936}
toolsdisplayorder       {b2721d73-1db4-4c62-bf78-c548a880142d}
timeout                 10
displaybootmenu         Yes

Windows Boot Loader
-------------------
identifier              {93f90e43-cae8-11df-b05a-c9177e705936}
device                  partition=\Device\HarddiskVolume3
path                    \Windows\system32\winload.exe
description             Windows Server 2008 R2 - Standard
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {6efb52bf-1766-41db-a6b3-0ee5eff72bd7}
recoverysequence        {93f90e44-cae8-11df-b05a-c9177e705936}
recoveryenabled         Yes
osdevice                partition=\Device\HarddiskVolume3
systemroot              \Windows
resumeobject            {93f90e42-cae8-11df-b05a-c9177e705936}
nx                      OptOut

Windows Boot Loader
-------------------
identifier              {93f90e3f-cae8-11df-b05a-c9177e705936}
device                  partition=C:
path                    \Windows\system32\winload.exe
description             Windows 7 - Professional
locale                  nl-NL
inherit                 {6efb52bf-1766-41db-a6b3-0ee5eff72bd7}
recoverysequence        {93f90e40-cae8-11df-b05a-c9177e705936}
recoveryenabled         Yes
osdevice                partition=C:
systemroot              \Windows
resumeobject            {93f90e3e-cae8-11df-b05a-c9177e705936}
nx                      OptIn

Real-mode Boot Sector
---------------------
identifier              {93f90e46-cae8-11df-b05a-c9177e705936}
device                  partition=C:
path                    \NST\AutoNeoGrub0.mbr
description             Ubuntu 10.04 - Lucid Lynx
```

Comment: I closed the question because @Sander indicated that he is no longer able to confirm any proposed solutions because the system was recommissioned.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this from Windows 7 Command Prompt instead of using third party tools. Follow steps below and let me know what happens.

After logging in to Windows 7, check what is the drive letter for your Windows Server 2008 partition.

**For this post, assume the drive letter for Windows Server 2008 drive as X:. However you must replace the X: with the actual drive letter.**

1. In Windows 7, open command prompt.
2. Type the following command and hit enter.

> bcdedit /set {93f90e43-cae8-11df-b05a-c9177e705936} device partition=X:

In above command where I have used X, you have to replace it with actual drive letter of Windows Server 2008 partition. And about **{93f90e43-cae8-11df-b05a-c9177e705936}**, I simply copied it from the EasyBCD boot menu you poster in the question. It is the identifier of Windows Server 2008 Bootloader object in the BCD Store.

Comment: Thank you for your input and sorry for my slow response, but I wasn't home to test the proposed solution. The reason EasyBCD show `partition=\Device\HarddiskVolume3` is simply because there is no drive letter assigned to my server partition in my Win7 OS. So assigning a drive letter and executing your command didn't resolve my problem :(

Answer (score 0):

If you are an advanced user you could use [Visual BCD Editor](http://www.boyans.net).
The tool allows really easy editing of every boot loader element by double clicking.
I would check in VisualBCD if winload.exe can be found on path (after mapping Server 2008 to drive letter).
SystemRoot path should also be accessible - drive_letter:\windows.

Check also if there is a difference in drive/paths for Server 2008 loader and its recovery loader.
Visual BCD displays and can edit all objects present in BCD.

If you are not so advanced:

1. Boot Win 7
2. Map drive of Server 2008 temporary to any drive letter.
3. Click on Server 2008 loader listed in Visual BCD.
4. Delete loader using right click and selecting "Delete object". Confirm.
5. Right click again and select "Create missing Windows loaders". Confirm.

This will have as result adding a new loader of type Windows 7/Vista. Rename description of new loader as you like - ie. "Server 2008"

Reboot - you should be able to select Server 2008 and boot to it.

For adding advanced repair options to Server 2008 see second part of [Dual-boot Repair](http://www.boyans.net/DualBootRepair.html) web page.

---

If there are still errors booting Server 2008 use system file check
"sfc.exe" on recovery console.
**sfc /scannow**

sfc can be run several times (with rebooting after each run) if errors are reported.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I've installed Visual BCD Editor and assigned a drive letter to my Windows Server partition (Z:). I couldn't see any faults, but I've uploaded the screens [here](http://img839.imageshack.us/img839/3109/screen1rn.png) and [here](http://img195.imageshack.us/img195/41/screen2lkb.png) if you want to double check. After this I made a backup in Visual BCD  and  went for the "not so advanced" option. Result was a totally new error, picture [here](http://img132.imageshack.us/img132/8606/screen3xt.png).

Comment: Because the new error looked worse, I've restored the backup and went for `sfc /scannow`. The command failed with the message `There is a system repair pending which requires reboot to complete. Restart Windows and run sfc again.` That's why I'll try [this](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itprogeneral/thread/48d20da9-0535-462f-b177-f30f48992203/) next.

Comment: When a loader entry reports "digital signature" problem it means you try to load a newer Windows OS with an older boot manager - e.g. boot manager from Windows 7 trying to load Windows 8. In a dual boot system the boot manager has to be from the newest OS ! You repair boot environment using "bcdboot R:\Windows" where R: drive is where the newest Windows OS is placed.